# Parsing the command and passing the filepath into fopen

Tags: c

The issues is in the pointer I guess. Please suggest any method to receive a command like "cat serverpath or filepath" and parse the command and to pass the path into `fopen(filepath, "r")`.

Here is the code for server:

```
time_t  start;
char    buf[BUFSIZ], *command, content;
int n,i;
FILE *fptr;

start = time(0);
(void) pthread_mutex_lock(&stats.st_mutex);
stats.st_concount++;
(void) pthread_mutex_unlock(&stats.st_mutex);
while (1) {
    bzero(buf, BUFSIZ);
    n = recv(fd, buf, BUFSIZ, 0);
    if (n < 0){
        errexit("echo read: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    else{
        printf("The client message: %s\n",buf);
    }

    strtok_r (buf, " ", &command);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    printf("%s\n",command);

    //char filename[100], c; 

    // printf("Enter the filename to open \n"); 
    // scanf("%s", command); 

    // Open file 
    fptr = fopen(command, "r"); 
    if (fptr == NULL) 
    { 
        printf("Cannot open file \n"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 

    // Read contents from file 
    content = fgetc(fptr); 
    while (content != EOF) 
    { 
        printf ("%c", content); 
        content = fgetc(fptr); 
    }
```

I get an error in fopen.

Comment: What is the problem with the existing code?

Comment: ask a question please

Comment: also please post all the code

Comment: the relevant code from main() is missing.   also what's `command` supposed to be? your code is not testable please read [mcve]

Comment: @user3121023 Thankyou sir. it worked

Answer (score 1):

You are using an `strtok_r`-internal data item, which actually shall not be used but just be passed in successive calls to `strtok_r`.

Write

```
command = strtok(buf," ");
if (command) {
   ....
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

I will guess the issue

`fgetc` returns an `int` not a `char`. see https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc
 So this can never be true

```
while (content != EOF)
```

so declare content as `int`;

Comment: `content == EOF` can be true if `char` is signed, but there another problem is distinguishing data `0xFF` from `EOF`. That is a reason why so many coders "get away with it" when processing a text file not containing that ambiguous data.